# Having increment issue in php

Tags: php, increment

I want the second column to be incremented but it instead takes the default counter value of 1. I want it as 1, 2, 3 etc.

Here's my code....

```
$sqlUsers = 'SELECT `user_id`, `name` FROM `users` ORDER BY `name`;'; // "outer" SQL statement to get a list of user names and IDs

// prepared statement
// NOTE: SUM(`sale_price`) AS s
$sqlPurchases = 'SELECT `transaction`,`date`,SUM(`sale_price`) AS s '
              . 'FROM `purchases` WHERE `user_id` = :id GROUP BY `transaction`;';
$purchStmt = $pdo->prepare($sqlPurchases);

echo '<h3>User Purchases</h3>', '<hr />', PHP_EOL;
echo '<table border=2>', PHP_EOL;

// run query() to get list of user IDs and names
foreach ($pdo->query($sqlUsers, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {

    // execute the prepared statement using $row data to get user_id
    $purchStmt->execute(array(':id' => $row['user_id']));
    $counter= 1;

    echo '<tr><th>', $row['name'], '</th><th>' . $counter++ . '</th><td>';

    echo '<table border=1>', PHP_EOL;
    echo '<tr><th>Transaction</th><th>Date</th><th>Amount</th></tr>', PHP_EOL;

    // fetch result
    while($result = $purchStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>', $result['transaction'], '</td>', PHP_EOL;
        echo '<td>', $result['date'], '</td>', PHP_EOL;
        // Echos SUM(`sale_price`) AS s
        echo '<td align="right">', $result['s'], '</td>', PHP_EOL;
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>', PHP_EOL;
    echo '</td></tr>', PHP_EOL;
}

echo '</table>', PHP_EOL;
```

?;

[Here's the output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyIjY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  `$counter= 1;` before foreach like that :-

```
$counter= 1;
foreach ($pdo->query($sqlUsers, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {
```

in your case every time counter value is 1

Comment: Thank you I will give it a try and give you feedback. Thanks once again

Answer (score 0):

Set your `counter` outside foreach

```
 $counter=1
    foreach ($pdo->query($sqlUsers, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) {

            // execute the prepared statement using $row data to get user_id
            $purchStmt->execute(array(':id' => $row['user_id']));


            echo '<tr><th>', $row['name'], '</th><th>' . $counter. '</th><td>';

            echo '<table border=1>', PHP_EOL;
            echo '<tr><th>Transaction</th><th>Date</th><th>Amount</th></tr>', PHP_EOL;

            // fetch result
            while($result = $purchStmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>', $result['transaction'], '</td>', PHP_EOL;
                echo '<td>', $result['date'], '</td>', PHP_EOL;
                // Echos SUM(`sale_price`) AS s
                echo '<td align="right">', $result['s'], '</td>', PHP_EOL;
                echo '</tr>';
            }



              echo '</table>', PHP_EOL;
                echo '</td></tr>', PHP_EOL;
    $counter++;
            }
```